# How to disable floating of maximized Chromium window?

Tags: chrome, awesome, settings

I'm using AwesomeWM. My rule for Chromium:

```
{ rule = { class = "Chromium" },
  properties = { tag = tags[1][9], floating = true, border_width = 0 } },
```

It works well, except Chromium window can be dragged using it's titlebar even if it's maximized.